# How to setup a Event Grid service(trigger) listen to a Resource Group for ever increasing storage blobs in multi storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

I'm setting up a "Event Grid Subscription + Storage Queue" which wants to listen to a resource group. I hope whenever a blob is created, a event will be sent to the storage queue. meanwhile storage accounts may also expand.

I have tried many methods, but the deterrent lies:
1. Event Grid Subscription, listening to a Resource group, only generates events when a storage account is created, not a blob. I want the even of uploaded blobs

2. "Fan-in pattern" : each Storage account has a Event Grid subscription-
   this method cannot scale out. because my storage accounts are ever increasing

Comment: what do you mean by "this method cannot scale out."? Have a Event Grid subscription for each Storage account. Behind this use Azure Functions to listen on that sub. These Functions can either consolidate all your events to some queue (e.g. Event Hub) or to another Event Grid subscription.

Comment: hello silent, 'one-to-one'(each Event Grid subscription for each Storage account)method cannot scale out, meaning: whenever I creating new storage accounts and upload files, the event Grid subscriptions won’t automatically be setup to listen to my SA. I have to manually set up one-by-one, which is not what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, seems it does not support to do that via event grid subscription.

When you create the event subscription, if you specify the `Topic Type` with `Resource Group`, the `Event Types` available is fixed, you could not access the event type like `Blob Created` which is available for storage account topic type.

[image]

My workaround is to create the event subscription along with your storage account created. Not sure which way you will use to create the storage account, but it is not difficult to create the storage account with automation, E.g. 1. use PowerShell [`New-AzStorageAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageaccount?view=azps-2.1.0), [`New-AzEventGridSubscription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.eventgrid/new-azeventgridsubscription?view=azps-2.1.0). 2. use ARM template [Storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2019-04-01/storageaccounts), [Event Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/2019-01-01/eventsubscriptions).

Comment: Thanks Joy for your nice solution! sadly I have checked, this cannot scale out. I chose to adopt the one-to-one solution, and when new storage account has been added, then new subscription will be setup.